# Combine Spheres

Tags: math, 3d, volume

Given a collection of spheres defined by their 3D position and radius.  Is there a trivial way to combine these together to give the smallest single sphere which encloses all spheres in the collection?

Answer: This problem is non-trivial.

However it is trivial to build a non-optimal sphere by calculating the maximum and minimum x,y,z values for each sphere (position+radius in each dimension) giving a bounding box.  This can then be used to derived a sub-optimal sphere.

Comment: Thanks, my searching skills are weak aparently!

Comment: It's ok, [duplication is not necessarily bad](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) - different words help guide more searchers to the answers